# Combine columns into list of key, value pairs (no UDF)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, key-value

I'd like to create a new column that is a JSON representation of some other columns.  key, value pairs in a list.

Source:

| origin | destination | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| toronto | ottawa | 5 |
| montreal | vancouver | 10 |

What I want:

| origin | destination | count | json |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| toronto | ottawa | 5 | [{"origin":"toronto"},{"destination","ottawa"}, {"count": "5"}] |
| montreal | vancouver | 10 | [{"origin":"montreal"},{"destination","vancouver"}, {"count": "10"}] |

(everything can be a string, doesn't matter).

I've tried something like:

```
df.withColumn('json', to_json(struct(col('origin'), col('destination'), col('count'))))
```

But it creates the column with all the `key:value` pairs in one object:

```
{"origin":"United States","destination":"Romania"}
```

Is this possible without a UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to hack around this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'json', 
    F.array(
        F.to_json(F.struct('origin')),
        F.to_json(F.struct('destination')),
        F.to_json(F.struct('count'))
    ).cast('string')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+--------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|origin  |destination|count|json                                                                |
+--------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|toronto |ottawa     |5    |[{"origin":"toronto"}, {"destination":"ottawa"}, {"count":"5"}]     |
|montreal|vancouver  |10   |[{"origin":"montreal"}, {"destination":"vancouver"}, {"count":"10"}]|
+--------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi mck thanks!  One reason I want to avoid the udf is for the performance concerns i've been reading out (i have yet to try pyarrow...).  Do you foresee any large computational expense with this approach (ie. calling to_json multiple times) if I run this on a big dataframe?

Comment: @AlexanderWitte I don't think it'll be expensive. to_json looks like a trivial operation to me.

Comment: @AlexanderWitte as a rule of thumb, Spark SQL functions will be way better than UDFs (even with pyarrow)

Answer (score 1):

Another way by creating array of maps column before calling `to_json`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    'json',
    F.to_json(F.array(*[F.create_map(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.columns]))
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+--------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|origin  |destination|count|json                                                              |
#+--------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|toronto |ottawa     |5    |[{"origin":"toronto"},{"destination":"ottawa"},{"count":"5"}]     |
#|montreal|vancouver  |10   |[{"origin":"montreal"},{"destination":"vancouver"},{"count":"10"}]|
#+--------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```